# JSON node in jquery, Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Tags: jquery, json

How to read the JSON nodes from below jquery code, currently, I am getting "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined" in the firebug, please let me know what am I doing wrong.

**Jquery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {


$('#search_btn_2').click(function(){

var queryValue = $('#search_string_2').val();

$('.my-div').hide();

$.getJSON( "${kb_endpoint_url}",
             { search_query : queryValue } 
         )

.done(function( data ) 
{
console.log("success:"+queryValue+":"+data);

alert(data.docs[0].title);                    

$('.my-div').html('<a href="'+data.docs[0].type+'">'+data.docs[0].title+'</a>'); 

})

.done(function() { console.log("second success"); })

.fail(function() { console.log("error"); })

.always(function() { console.log("finished"); $('.my-div').show(); });                   

});

});
```

**JSON**

```
{
   "response":{
      "start":0,
      "docs":[
         {
            "summary":"image/img1.jpg",
            "id":"17",
            "title":"Varun",
            "votecount":0,
            "_version_":1192256,
            "type":"User"
         }
      ],
      "numFound":1
   },
   "responseHeader":{
      "status":0,
      "QTime":1,
      "params":{
         "indent":"true",
         "q":"varun",
         "wt":"json"
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`data.docs` is undefined. Per your JSON structure, you're looking for `data.response.docs`.

Answer (score 2):

You are getting it wrong, your hierarchy is:

```
data -> response -> docs
```

however, you are trying to directly access docs (`data -> docs`), which is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

The `docs` property belongs to the `data.response` object, so you need to use  `data.response.docs[0]` instead of `data.docs[0]`.

In your object there is no property called `data.docs` that is the reason for the error.